# How to display name instead of id in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

im using visual studio with asp.net core.My database is MSSQL. Im following tutorial from youtube. Currently i ran a problem where it display the id instead of name.
**Here is the picture of what i try to create/add**
[image]
**Here is the picture of my problem**
[image]Since i dont know what code to include i just give my github link [text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type of `model.COURT_TYPE` is `int`, so the page display `1` is no problem, But your prupose is display the dropdownlist's text not the value, So you can use linq to select in viewbag.

I write a simple demo here.

```
    //Here the Id is your COUNT_TYPE, in your code, 
      you use select from db to get the COUNT_TYPE, 
      For testing convenience, I just hard code here to get the 
      data from other action.

     //In your code, You save the value and text of the dropdownlist in the database, 
      I just hard code here and use `items` of type List<T> to include them.

public IActionResult Privacy(int id)
        {

            List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item1 in items)
            {
                test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item1.Name, Value = item1.Id.ToString() });
            }
            ViewBag.Items1 = test;


            Item item = new Item();
            item.Id = id;
            return View(item);
        }
```

**page**

```
@model ViewBagTest.Models.Item
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
    var test = ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Items1).Where(x => x.Value == Model.Id.ToString()).Select(x=>x.Text).First();
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<h1>@test</h1>
```

[image]

Comment: thank for your time. I already change COURT_TYPE to Court_Types.Name but the result still the same

Comment: instead it display nothing

Comment: Hi@Mana, I try to run your code in my project, Unfortunately it always fail, so i can just edite my anser and write a simple demo here to show you my method, I hope you can get my point. I use viewbag to include the value and text of dropdownlist and pass them to page, Then select the text  in viewbag by `viewbag.value==model.COURT_TYPE`

Comment: hi @Xinran Shen, i already take a look at your code, but still have no idea on where i should implement, i already add a localDb on my github, i think you can run it now, just change the appsettings.json. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: ah im dumb, already found the solution. The foreign key should be the same as navigation. That solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

As you said it is displaying ID instead of name because in your code, you are binding ID itself.

In your index view,

```
      <th>
            <i class="@sortModel.GetColumn("COURT_TYPE").SortIcon" arial- 
            hidden="true"></i>

            <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-           
        sortExpression="@sortModel.GetColumn("COURT_TYPE").SortExpression">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.COURT_TYPE)
            </a>
        </th>
```

you can see above that you are binding model.Court_type.

Now if you look at your model,

```
    //Cascade|Dropdown

    [ForeignKey("COURT_TYPE")]
    [Display(Name = "COURT_TYPE")]
    public int? COURT_TYPE { get; set; }
    public virtual COURT_TYPE Court_Types { get; set; }
```

As you can see Court_Type is INT so definitely it will display INT value. If you want to display name then you have get through Court_Types object.

In another way,

```
         public PaginatedList<LawReview> GetItems(string SortProperty, SortOrder sortOrder, string SearchText = "", int pageIndex = 1, int pageSize = 5)
        {
            List<LawReview> items;

            if (SearchText != "" && SearchText != null)
            {
                items = _context.LawReviews.Where(n => n.LAWREVIEW_ID.ToString().Contains(SearchText) || n.JUDGMENT_NAME.Contains(SearchText) || n.JUDGMENT_NAME_VERSUS.Contains(SearchText) || n.JUDGMENT_NAME_ADDITIONAL.Contains(SearchText) || n.Court_Types.Name.Contains(SearchText) || n.Judge_Names.Name.Contains(SearchText) || n.JUDGMENT_NUMBER.Contains(SearchText) || n.JUDGMENT_DATE.Contains(SearchText) || n.HEADNOTE.Contains(SearchText) || n.Judgment_Countries.Name.Contains(SearchText) || n.States.Name.Contains(SearchText) || n.Judgment_Languages.Name.Contains(SearchText) || n.Catchword_Lv1.Name_Lv1.Contains(SearchText) || n.Catchword_Lv2.Name_Lv2.Contains(SearchText) || n.Catchword_Lv3.Name_Lv3.Contains(SearchText) || n.Catchword_Lv4.Name_Lv4.Contains(SearchText) || n.VERDICT.Contains(SearchText))
                    .Include(u => u.Court_Types)
                    .ToList();
            }
            else
                items = _context.LawReviews
                    .Include(u => u.Court_Types).Include(r => r.Judge_Names).Include(s => s.Judgment_Countries).Include(t => t.Judgment_Languages).Include(v => v.Catchword_Lv1).Include(w => w.Catchword_Lv2).Include(x => x.Catchword_Lv3).Include(y => y.Catchword_Lv4).Include(z => z.States)
                    .ToList();

            items = DoSort(items, SortProperty, sortOrder);

            PaginatedList<LawReview> retItems = new PaginatedList<LawReview>(items, pageIndex, pageSize);

            return retItems;
        }
```

Here in items, you can use select and get the name from courtType object which I believe would be in relation with your primary table.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net Core Web App (MVC) - NET 6

Make sure to check in your ***index.schtml*** file you are binding the right attribute and not **Id**. In my case I want to display the list of products and their corresponding category.

```
      <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
      </td>
```